# Windows authentication over Service Fabric Reverse Proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

I've setup an Asp.Net Core 2.0 application following [the guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

The goal is to enable Windows Authentication. I've enabled NTLM and Negotiate. I'm working (and will update) on testing Kerberos and Basic as well, but I fear I might not get the automatic sign-in that negotiate brings.

The application works correctly, and when hosted on Service Fabric I can access it directly from the server IP and port. Windows authenticates correctly, everyone is happy, birds are singing, rainbows appear in the sky... its great.

However, when I try to access the application via the Service Fabric Reverse Proxy service, I hit a wall. My browser prompts me for credentials, and will not accept anything that I pass into it.

I fear this may be a limitation of the built in reverse proxy, but this is something so common that its hard to believe that to be the case.

Is there a way to enable pass-through Windows authentication for the built in proxy?

**Note:** This is not hosted in Azure, but on premises.

**Update:** Enabling Basic Authentication and Kerberos didn't help either. Basic authentication actually further complicated the issue. With just Basic authentication enabled, I got repeated 401s, even when connecting directly to the service.

Comment: Windows auth doesn't handle proxies well. NTLM and Kerberos are bound to the connection, you can't forward without enabling Kerberos delegation. Basic auth is the one I would have expected to work.

Comment: I'll try it again with just Basic to see what happens. There was some odd behavior where it seemed to authenticate, but then I was still given 401s. Will update today. I had both Kerberos and Basic enabled at the same time before.